# jquery ajax load animation shouldn't show (delay) when content finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, animation

I have a small problem with my loading animation. The animation starts and stops well. But if the content is loaded faster then the animatin is played, i want that it is not shown (start, delay)

I try it like this

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function (data) {
        /* Ajax Loading... einblenden */
        $('.loading_box').delay(500).fadeIn(500);

    },

    success: function (data) {
        $(".content_main").html(data);
    },

    complete: function(data) {
        $('.loading_box').stop().fadeOut(500);
    }
});
```

Like this the animation is always shown. How can i stop it if the content is loaded?

Comment: Did you try removing the fadeOut in the complete handler

Comment: oh yes, of course, the success handler is closed... i've much more code in it

Comment: Would you mind explaining the problem more clearly? I'm not sure if you want the animation to skip to the end of the animation when the data loads too fast or to just stop completely. I am specifically confused by "But if the content is loaded faster then the animatin is played, i want that it is not shown (start, delay)"

Comment: if I removing the fadeOut the animation is always shown, but my target is... start request, don't show animation, if response less then 1s, otherwise show anination.

Comment: when you call ajax "var start = new Date()", when its successed/complete calculate time difference. if smaller than your animation check again

Comment: @marathonman: note, `var start` must be outside of the function or else `start` will not be visible anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery function [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) is defined as such:

```
.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )
```

You can use `$('.loading_box').stop(true, true)` if you want it to skip to the end of the animation. Since your animation already takes 1s to complete and you want to not show the animation if the ajax completes in less than 1s, you can just have the animation skip to the end unconditionally because it will already be done if more than 1s has passed.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function (data) {
        /* Ajax Loading... einblenden */
        $('.loading_box').delay(500).fadeIn(500);

    },

    success: function (data) {
        $('.loading_box').stop().fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(".content_main").html(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: If i do it this way, the animation is shown always... fade out and then show the content.

Comment: My target is... if the connection is fast enough... content is loaded in maybe less 1s the animation is not shown and if loading need more time (like pic) the animation should shown.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you... this is what i needed... my solution looks like so...

```
$.ajax({
    /* Ajax Funktions Event Handler, wird ausgefürhrt bevor der Request an den Server gesendet wird */
    beforeSend: function (data) {
        /* Ajax Loading... einblenden */
        $('.loading_box').delay(500).fadeIn(300);
    },

    /* Ajax Funktions Event Handler, wird ausgefürhrt nach dem der Request erfolgreich durchgeführt, und der Response empfangen wurde */
    success: function (data) {
        $(".content_main").html(data).fadeIn();

    },

    /* Ajax Funktions Event Handler, wird ausgefürhrt unabhänig davon ob der Request erfolgreich war oder nicht */
    complete: function(data) {
        /* Ajax Loading... wieder ausblenden */
        $('.loading_box').stop(true, false).fadeOut(500);
    }
});
```

and it works... i had to play a little bit wit the delay time.